# Create hash-tag buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a string the looks like this: `#romantic #TLVLove #tagsforlikes #funday #telavivcity #summervacation` (of course this string is dynamically and will be changed all the time).

I want to present it like this:

[image]

(Separate buttons for each tag with a space between every `UIButton`).

I know how to separate the string to other strings (after every empty space) and to create a `UIButton` with that title, but how do I know what size should the button be and in what place (origin) that won't go out of screen (the line should break to another line if there isn't enough space for the tag).

Comment: May be you need that https://github.com/zoonooz/ZFTokenField. If yes then you can customize your view as per need.

Comment: you have to access created button size

Comment: then after check created button width is more then parent view

Comment: You can use collectionView, calculate text size and create cell with calculated size

Comment: refere https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tags, and in that asjtagsview are easy to implement, https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/asjtagsview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `UICollectionView` self sizing cells, what you need to do is

**First**

Take a **UICollectionView** and take a button in that **UICollectionViewCell** and set the **constraints** of that **UIButton** from all the 4 sides ie from left, right, bottom and left.

[image]

**Second**

Now after setting constraint you can in your viewDidLoad you need to define `estimatedItemSize` of your `UICollectionView`'s `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let collectionViewFlowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    collectionViewFlowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 34, height: 50)

}
```

here `collectionView` is `IBOutlet` of my `UICollectionView`

**Third**

For the names of Buttons i have taken an Static Array you can take it as dynamic from your data

```
let arrButtons = ["#B1","#ButtonButton2","#Bu3","#Buttontton11","#Buttodasfdsafasdn1","#Bu3","#Buttofn1","#Buttodasfdsafasdntodn11"]
```

**Fourth**

After that you just need to implement Data Source methods of your UICollectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! RPCollectionViewCell

    cell.btn.setTitle(arrButtons[indexPath.row], for: .normal)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrButtons.count

}
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: But the distance between the cells is REALLY big

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrayOfStrings = hashTagString.componentSeparatedBy(" ");// This will give you an array of strings separated by space token.
```

Now Either you create button by CollectionView , Dynamically allocation buttons on UIView or use any approach you want to draw. 
If you are still confuse refer to Mr. Rajat answer and instead of assigning hard coded values to array like this,

```
let arrButtons = ["#B1","#ButtonButton2","#Bu3","#Buttontton11","#Buttodasfdsafasdn1","#Bu3","#Buttofn1","#Buttodasfdsafasdntodn11"];
```

just use the arrayOfString that i am creating by spliting your string into array.

if you want to draw round corner borders on your button just add these two lines before `return cell`

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
cell.layer.maskToBound = true
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor()
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

Comment: That was really helpful ...Thanks